# Is there a way for an app to require multi-factor auth when using Login with Microsoft Account?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-account

I couldn't find a way to require the user to do MFA authentication when using Microsoft Account login. Am I missing something?

Azure AD provides a way to achieve this. Is this something that is coming in the future?

Comment: The limitation now is that you will have to login to the myapps portal first and the app should be registered on Azure AD. Additionally, if you have any suggestions for Azure AD or would like any features be added in the future, just provide your feedback on the Azure AD uservoice page here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory

Comment: My question is about apps that use Microsoft Account for login, not Azure AD. There doesn't seem to be a way to require MFA for Microsoft Accounts. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, with the instructions below you can require MFA for Microsoft Accounts when login app. But as I mentioned the app should connect to Azure AD and users should login myapps first.

Comment: I am not using Azure AD, so how can I connect to it? I am using the Login with Microsoft identity provider.

Comment: If so, then unfortunately no way to achieve your goal at this moment. We need Azure AD to apply access policies to these Microsoft Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that requires MFA when using a Microsoft Account to log in the Azure AD managed applications. You can configure the MFA and location based access rules on the Azure classic portal like following:

[image]

If the Microsoft Account users are members of the application assigned user groups, then he/she will get prompt to complete MFA before they can access the application on the Access Panel (https://myapps.microsoft.com), like below:

[image]

Comment: My application is not registered with Azure AD, it is registered with Microsoft Login. Are there instructions for that?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more about how did you register your app with Microsoft Login?

Comment: I used this [site](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/?mkt=en-us#/appList) to register an app for Login with Microsoft.